# Problem with the DateTime "0001-01-01T00:00:00"

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, model, format

I have a problem with my date. I do the insert with the postman and no matter what I enter I always get back "0001-01-01T00:00:00".

Would also like to limit the output to just the date.

I am very grateful for any help

thank you

```
Model:

public class BusinessTripDocument
    {
        

        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string StartLocation { get; set; }
      [JsonPropertyName("startDateTime")]
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
        public string Destination { get; set; }
        public DateTime DestinationDate { get; set; }
        public string Transportation { get; set; }
        public string SuperiorsApproval { get; set; }
```

```
// POST: api/Businesstripdocuments
       
        [HttpPost("new/{eId}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<BusinessTripDocument>> PostBusinesstripdocuments(long eId, BusinessTripDocument businesstripdocuments)
        {
            Employee employee = await _context.Employees.FindAsync(eId);
            //  businesstripdocuments.Employee = employee;
            //   _context.Businesstripdocuments.Add(businesstripdocuments);
            employee.addDocument(businesstripdocuments);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return CreatedAtAction("GetBusinesstripdocuments", new { id = businesstripdocuments.Id }, businesstripdocuments);
        }
```

[Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ub012.png)

Answer (score 1):

Just from the code you've shown- to me it looks like you should just need to supply the `DataType` attribute to your Model?

```cs
//using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
public class BusinessTripDocument 
{
    ...
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [JsonPropertyName("startDateTime")]
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Sorry i have forgotten to show the using, but the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations is at the using

Comment: @Notte , I only added the commented using to show which one to use in order to add the `[DataType(DataType.Date)]` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you could do two ways:
1.- The date could be inside the method PostBusinesstripdocuments
2.- The date could be string in class BusinessTripDocument and after conver to datetime.

her is the example:
[image]

Comment: How can i catch the date type string, is it the businesstripdocuments? I think the string has always the same date "0001-01-01T00:00:00"